# Rotate for p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I'm working on a experimental clock on p5.js web editor.
I did a simple ellipse that repeat itself every second.
But, as i a begginner, i don't understand why it start on the left corner. I trying to rotate it, because i want it to start on the bottom center on my canvas.

If someone can help me, thank you so much !

Here is my code :

```
function setup(){
  createCanvas(600,600);
  smooth();
  
}

function draw(){
  
  background(230,340,344);
  
  let hr = hour();
  let mn = minute();
  let sc = second();
  
 
  for (let i=1; i < sc ; i++) {
  fill(23,34,456)
  stroke (1);
  ellipse(i*6,250,60,100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `rotate()`, but I think that's much more complicated than you need. I would just swap the coordinates of the center of the ellipses:

```js
ellipse(250,i*6,60,100);
```

But wait, now it's going down! So in order to have it move upward, we can simply change the sign of the `y` coordinate:

```js
ellipse(250,-i*6,60,100);
```

But now it's just going off the top, so we translate it down to start at the bottom:

```js
ellipse(250, height-i*6,60,100);
```

You could also change it so that the ellipse makes it all the way to the top when a minute passes (use `i*10` instead of `i*6`). Another way is to use [`map()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/map):

```js
ellipse(250, map(i, 0, 60, height, 0), 60, 100);
```

`map()` does linear interpolation; if `i==0`, then it outputs `height`, if `i==60`, it outputs `0`, and for the values in between, puts it on a straight line between them.